# Postgres - group rows by user, return one row per user in each group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `purchases` table:

```
-----------------
user_id | amount
-----------------
1       | 12                     
1       | 4                     
1       | 8     
2       | 23                    
2       | 45                    
2       | 7
```

I want a query that will return one row per `user_id`, but the row that I want for each `user_id` is where the `amount` is the *smallest* per `user_id`. So I should get as my result set:

```
-----------------
user_id | amount
-----------------                   
1       | 4                                        
2       | 7
```

Using `DISTINCT` on the `user_id` column ensures I don't get duplicate user's, but I don't know how to make it so that returns the user row with the *fewest* `amount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement requires ouput of a row that equates to the smallest amount, e.g. the table includes a transaction date and you need this in the output, then a convenient method is to use `row_number() over()` to select the wanted rows. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   user_id  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,amount   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,trandate DATE   NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(user_id,amount,trandate) VALUES (1,12,'2020-09-12');
INSERT INTO mytable(user_id,amount,trandate) VALUES (1,4,'2020-10-02');
INSERT INTO mytable(user_id,amount,trandate) VALUES (1,8,'2020-11-12');
INSERT INTO mytable(user_id,amount,trandate) VALUES (2,23,'2020-12-02');
INSERT INTO mytable(user_id,amount,trandate) VALUES (2,45,'2021-01-12');
INSERT INTO mytable(user_id,amount,trandate) VALUES (2,7,'2021-02-02');

select
user_id, amount, trandate
from (
    select user_id, amount, trandate
        , row_number() over(partition by user_id order by amount) as rn
    from mytable
    ) t
where rn = 1
```

result:

```
+---------+--------+------------+
| user_id | amount |  trandate  |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       1 |      4 | 2020-10-02 |
|       2 |      7 | 2021-02-02 |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

*demonstartion of this at db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=015f7cddc12036f4c5dbb8278abeb930)*

Comment: Why would you not use `select user_id, min(amount) from purchases group by user_id`. Isn't that more performant? Honest question

Comment: @hrmnjt Using `min(amount)` doesn't automatically align to its transaction date, but using `row_number` returns the row so you can keep the minimum amount and its transaction date together (or any data on that row) - so its not a question of performance, but of data integrity.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (user) t.*
from t
order by user, amount;
```

Note:  If you just want the smallest amount, then `group by` would be the typical solution:

```
select user, min(amount)
from t
group by user;
```

`Distinct on` is a convenient Postgres extension that makes it easy to get one row per group -- and it often performs better than other methods.